# Sanitize Content: removing markup from Amazon's content

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

I'm using Amazon Web Service to get product descriptions of various items. The problem is that Amazon's content contains mark up that is sometimes destructive to the layout of my web page (e.g. unclosed DIVs, etc.).

I want to sanitize the content I get from Amazon. My solution would be to do the following (my initial list so far):

- Remove unnecessary tags such as `div`, `span`, etc. while keeping tags like `p`, `ul`, `ol`, etc.
- Remove all attributes from all the tags (e.g. seems like there are `style` attributes in some of the tags)
- Remove excess white space (e.g. multiple spaces, carriage returns, new lines, tabs, etc.)
- Etc.

Before I go off trying to build my solution, I'm wondering if anyone has a better idea (or an already existing solution). Thanks.

Comment: Does it need to be accomplished by regular expressions? They're possibly the worse tool to parse HTML.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I was thinking that some might be done with RegEx (e.g. whitespaces, etc.). I might try to put the mark up in a DOM and use XPath, etc. to manipulate the snippet of mark up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it's the best idea or not:

Remove excess whitespace:

`preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($v))`

Remove attributes from HTML elements:

`preg_replace('/<([^\s>]+) [^>]+>/', '<$1>', $v)`

Remove specific elements:

`preg_replace('/<\/?(div|span)[^>]*>/', '', $v)`